# how to write a code to open a database view using @dblookup from lotus replica server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula, lotus-designer

i am using two lotus domino servers(main server and lotus replica server), my all mail databases and workflow database are store in two servers.

Main sever name = "sanvar"

Replica Server Name = "varsan"

Mail and workflow database are replicating and working fine but workflow forms not working when my Main server down state.

ex: i am getting employees name from empentry database and it's code like

@DbLookup( "" : "NoCache" ; "sanvar": "empentry" ; "master" ; @Name([CN];@UserName) ; 2); 
but my main server down condition i am accessing a form through replica server it showing :

"SERVER ERROR".

pls suggest me how to get user name from replica server.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `"sanvar": "empentry"` in your argument list with `@DbName`, like this:

```
@DbLookup( "" : "NoCache" ; @DbName ; "master" ; @Name([CN];@UserName) ; 2);
```

This will return the name of the current server and database in a list. It is a very useful function, and can be combined with @Subset to just get the server name in cases where that's all you need. Please see the doc for @DbName [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DBNAME.html).